# How to import core php module into yii framework?

Tags: php, html, file, yii, php-5.3

I have document upload problem in yii framework. I tried to upload using yii concept so that it could successful.

I used core PHP concept. it upload in core php with separate core php folder.

but i want import that core php module into yii framework. i used Yii::import method like i mention below

```
   <?php Yii::import('application.controllers.submitForm.php');?>
```

form like

```
<form method="post" action="<?php Yii::import('application.controllers.submitForm.php');?>" id="frmContact" name="frmContact" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <span id="responseMessage"></span><br/>
            <fieldset class="formClass" id="formClass">
                    <p>
                       <label>Name: </label>
               <input type="text" name="name">
                </p>

                <p>
              <label>Document: </label>
               <input type="file" name="updDocument"><br/><br/>
               <span class="docFormate">Only JPG,PNG and DOC allowed with less than 2MB size.</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                       <label>Message: </label>
               <textarea name="message"></textarea>
                </p>
                <p>
                       <span id="submitBtn">
             <input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Submit" class="button marL114" onclick="return validForm()">
             <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" class="button">
                       </span>
                       <span id="flashShow"></span>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
      </form>
</div>
```

submitForm.php is present in controller folder

so that how can i import and execute the file please suggest me suitable answer
`

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for [`Yii::import()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#import-detail)

> Imports a class or a directory.

You are trying to create a url therefore `Yii::app()->createUrl()` or `CController::createUrl()` should be used in.

**However**

You are using Yii wrong. `submitForm.php` should be a controller. Files in the `protected` folder cannot be accessed directly via url.